# Runtime 'default is not a function' when importing fp from fastify-plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fastify

I'm trying to get `fastify-plugin` to play nice with ES6 shenanigans.

The following works fine,

```
const fp = require('fastify-plugin');

export default fp(async (server, opts, next) => {
  // ...
  next();
});
```

but swap that ol' `require` out with `import`, i.e.

```
import fp from 'fastify-plugin';

export default fp(async (server, opts, next) => {
  // ...
  next();
});
```

and it fails runtime, complaining that `fastify_plugin_1.default is not a function` even though TypeScript doesn't say a word.

I'm very confused by this. The `default` export is defined in `fastify-plugin`s `plugin.d.ts`, so logically it doesn't complain. But it also defines `module.exports` to be (what I assume must be) the `fp` function in `plugin.js`. So why on earth does it say that `default` is not a function? Is `module.exports` different from `export default` or?

FWIW I'm on,

```
  "dependencies": {
    "fastify": "^3.1.1",
    "fastify-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
```

and I've tried various `tsconfig.json` tricks and different `import`s. Nothing works (well, except `require`).

Comment: in `tsconfig.json` set `"esModuleInterop": true` under `"compilerOptions"`. Note that the `plugin.d.ts` file is in error. Compare https://github.com/fastify/fastify-plugin/blob/master/plugin.d.ts#L16 and https://github.com/fastify/fastify-plugin/blob/master/plugin.js#L71. `plugin.d.ts` should be written using `export =` instead of `export default`

Comment: Note that, if `plugin.d.ts` were correct in using `export default`, your first snippet would fail to run.

Comment: not reproducible with: fastify@3.13.0, fastify-plugin@2.3.4